# C++ Programming, Cannot understand errors

Tags: c++, math

I am a beginner at c++ programming, and this is only my second program. I am getting a consistent error of "expected unqualified-id before..." idk what it means and cannot solve it. This is on lines 21,27,29,33,35,38,40,43,45.48,54,56,59,61,64,66,70.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

int main ();

int a, b, c, x,y;
int discriminant;
double x1, x2;

int countdataisinvalid=0;
int countdataisvalid=0;
int countnolastterm=0;
int countonexvalue=0;
int countnomiddleterm=0;
int counttwoxterms=0;

while(!cin.eof)
    {
        a*x*x+b*x+c;
    }


    if (a==0),
        countdataisinvalid++;
        {
            cout << "A is 0, data invalid." << endl;
        }

    else if, (discriminant < 0),
        countdataisinvalid++;
        {
            cout << "The square is a negative number, data invalid."     <<              endl;
        }
    else,
        countdataisvalid++;
        {
            cout << " Data set is valid." << endl;
        }
    if (c==0),
        countnolastterm++;
        {
            cout << "C is 0, there is no last term." << endl;
        }
{
x1 = (-b + sqrt(b*b-4*a*c))/(2*a);
x2 = (-b - sqrt(b*b-4*a*c))/(2*a);

cout.precision(3);
}
    if (x1==x2),
        countonexvalue++;
        {
            cout << "Only one x value." << endl;
        }
    else, if (x1==-x2),
        countnomiddleterm++;
        {
            cout << "There is no middle term." << endl;
        }
    else
        counttwoxterms++;
        {
            cout << "There are two x values." << endl;
        }

{
y = a*x1*x1+b*x1+c
y = a*x2*x2+b*x2+c

cout << "When x is " << x << "y is " << y << endl;
}
```

Comment: Your code contains a possibly infinite loop and many harmful commas that are where they shouldn't be.

Comment: `int main ();` *declares* a function called main, but you need to start a *definition* if you want to put code such as `if` and `while` statements inside, for that you need `int main {`, and a `}` after the code the function's to execute.

Comment: @MikeCAT can you possibly be more specific about how to fix it. i dont really know much thats why

Comment: Separately, `while(!cin.eof) { a*x*x+b*x+c; }` won't compile because `eof` is a function and needs to be called a la `cin.eof()`, and if that's fixed it will hang the program unless `eof` is true before reaching the loop.  **You should throw this program away** and start simply, getting an empty main to run, then adding a little bit piece by piece while keeping it working.  Start slowly and build up.

Comment: your program doesn't make any sense. you should probably look at this online tutorial of C++ before asking questions: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/

Comment: That program is too far from being the shortest program that demonstrates your problem clearly. A [mcve] for this is something like `int main(); return 0;` and you can work up from there.

Answer (score 1):

Your code contains too many errors. You should learn C++ again with writing simple programs.

At least this code compiles.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{ // use { to begin definition of function, not ;

    // initialize ariables for in case the reading fails
    int a = 0, b = 0, c = 0, x = 0, y = 0;
    int discriminant = 0;
    double x1 = 0, x2 = 0;

    int countdataisinvalid=0;
    int countdataisvalid=0;
    int countnolastterm=0;
    int countonexvalue=0;
    int countnomiddleterm=0;
    int counttwoxterms=0;

    // you should read numbers instead of writing possibly infinite loop and meaningless statement
    cin >> a >> b >> c >> x >> discriminant >> x1 >> x2;


    if (a==0) // remove extra comma
        {
            countdataisinvalid++; // move this statement to right position
            cout << "A is 0, data invalid." << endl;
        }

    else if (discriminant < 0) // remove extra commas
        {
            countdataisinvalid++; // move this statement to right position
            cout << "The square is a negative number, data invalid."     <<              endl;
        }
    else // remove extra comma
        {
            countdataisvalid++; // move this statement to right position
            cout << " Data set is valid." << endl;
        }
    if (c==0) // remove extra comma
        {
            countnolastterm++; // move this statement to right position
            cout << "C is 0, there is no last term." << endl;
        }
    {
        x1 = (-b + sqrt(b*b-4*a*c))/(2*a);
        x2 = (-b - sqrt(b*b-4*a*c))/(2*a);

        cout.precision(3);
    }
        if (x1==x2) // remove extra comma
            {
              countonexvalue++; // move this statement to right position
                cout << "Only one x value." << endl;
            }
        else if (x1==-x2) // remove extra commas
            {
                countnomiddleterm++; // move this statement to right position
                cout << "There is no middle term." << endl;
            }
        else
            {
            counttwoxterms++; // move this statement to right position
                    cout << "There are two x values." << endl;
            }

    {
        y = a*x2*x2+b*x2+c; // add semicolon and remove useless statement

        cout << "When x is " << x << "y is " << y << endl;
    }

    return 0; // add a statement to return some value
} // add this as end of definition of function
```